# request.is_ajax() ajax request not working in django

Tags: python, json, django, ajax, django-views

In the following code, I am getting redirect to this text **{'saved': 1}** instead of the template which is rendered by the view, here, I used **request.is_ajax()** function. and I am using Django Version: 3.1.1

**Views.py**

```
def add_Patient(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        add = Patient(
            name=request.POST['name'],
            gender=request.POST['gender'],
            birthdate=request.POST['birthdate'],
            age=request.POST['age']
        )
        add.save()
        return JsonResponse({'saved': 1})
    return render(request, 'Patient_template/add_patient.html')
```

**add_patient.html**

```
<script>
        const form = document.getElementById("patient");
        form.addEventListener("submit", submitHandler);

        function submitHandler(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url : {% url 'Patient:add' %},
                type : 'POST',
                data : $("#form").serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(msg){
                    if (msg.saved === 1){
                        alert("Data Saved");
                        form.reset();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

So help me to find an alternative solution or solve this problem.

Comment: There seems to be a syntax error in your js code. The url value must be a string, i.e. surround it with quotes: `url: "{% url 'Patient:add' %}"`.

Comment: `request.is_ajax` is [deprecated since 3.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.is_ajax). (Simplest solution would be to use a different view for the ajax request)

Comment: add headers:{'X-CSRFToken':"{{csrf_token}}"}, within ajax call.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Please explain in detail, How to create a different view for an ajax request.